# typescript function return different type of result in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
myFuncResult interface {
  abc: string
}

function myFunc():myFuncResult {
 if(something) return { abc:'abc' } //ok here

 return 'result' //but this line gave me warning
}
```

I have 2 kind of result type (object and string) base on a condition, how can I declare that in my interface?

Comment: You can use type instead of interface, like this. `type myFuncResult = { abc: string } | string`

Comment: What is the warning, I am not able to see any warning. What is your TS version?Your syntax to write function is incorrect as well. it should be `export interface myInterface` You have interface keyword declared afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Since you're returning two different types/interfaces (it can either be `myFuncResult` or a string), why don't you use the pipe operator to create a union type?

```
function myFunc(): myFuncResult | string {
    if (something)
        return { abc:'abc' };

    return 'result';
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a union type directly as such:

```
type myFuncResult = { abc: string } | string;

function myFunc(): myFuncResult {
    if (something)
        return { abc:'abc' };

    return 'result';
}
```

Comment: const { abc } = myFunc() // I got warning on this line, doesn't work

Comment: @Jennifer Of course not, because `myFunc()` does not always return an object that can be destructured

Comment: correct, thus your solution won't work, how to get rid of the warning on my IDE?

Comment: You're changing the nature of your question: in your question you say that returning a string results in an error. My answer fixes that. But now you're changing the scope of the question of destructuring the return value of your function? It's not mentioned anywhere in your original question. Also, it is in your code that you want to sometimes return a string value: how are you supposed to destructure it then?

Comment: no no, I have no problem running my function, just that I'm annoyed but typescript. Because my logic it has multiple condition and the returned result is object and string.

Comment: Yes, and your question is?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of `string` is not equal to interface type `myFuncResult`. You can return type `myFuncResult` with `abc` variable:

```
myFunc(): myFuncResult {
    if (something) 
        return { abc:'abc' } //ok here    
    return {abc: 'result'} //but this line gave me warning
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In addition, you can return `null` if it is eligible for you:

```
myFunc():myFuncResult {
    if (something) 
       return { abc:'abc' } //ok here

    return null;
}
```

[A work example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-heroapp-fjwkt6?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: then it beat the purpose, I don't want to go into a library and make my own library

Comment: @Jennifer could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I have multiple return type, how can I remove warning from typeacript?

Comment: @Jennifer I've tested your code and warnings are not found. [Work stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-heroapp-fjwkt6?file=app/app.component.ts)